# What's a Unicode character for an arrow without a head?

Tags: unicode

What is a Unicode character for an arrow without a head?  A dash will do, of course, but it's not at the same height, length or thickness as a Unicode arrow in general:

> ## → vs -

I've looked in all three Unicode arrow sets (U+2190-21FF, U+27F0-27FF and U+2900-297F), but all their arrows are headed.

Is there a Unicode character that is (expected to be) a line of the same length, height and thickness as the lines used in the standard Unicode arrows?

Comment: maybe `\u2015`?  I just googled unicode dashes https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category/Pd  and http://jkorpela.fi/dashes.html   try `\uFF0D` and `\u2014`

Comment: @barlop That seems to be at a slightly different height : ―→

Comment: Seems to depend on font. In Arial they are the same height.  In courier new(default notepad font), they are different heights.  I see in your youtube comment they show as same height so the font used on superuser shows them as same height.

Comment: @barlop Yes, me too - the difference was much more pronounced when writing the comment, but as soon as it switched to the display font it disappeared.  Maybe I should just find something that works with my current font: I was hoping that there was an 'official' headless arrow character, which would be more likely to work the same way across fonts.

Comment: well, could choose the font to suit it. Or even a script that identifies those characters and makes sure they show in a suitable font, while leaving the rest of your document in the font you want for the rest of it.